# Вопрос по работе с двумя календарями aiogram 3

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Только недавно погрузился в python + aiogram, начал делать своего бота .. многое непонятно ... но вроде как постепенно решаются возникающие вопросы. Сейчас возникла проблема, прошу помощи как ее решить.
В общем бот на aiogram 3, в котором есть 2 inline кнопки по выводу заказов и продаж на определенную дату.
По описания работы календря для aiogram 3 https://github.com/noXplode/aiogram_calendar понятно и работает корректно то, если это вопрос с одним календарем ... а мне фактически надо 2.
В описании https://github.com/noXplode/aiogram_calendar при нажатии на кнопку календаря сначала срабатывает

```
@dp.message(F.text.lower() == 'navigation calendar')
```

после чего срабатывает

```
@dp.callback_query(SimpleCalendarCallback.filter())
```

... у меня же фактически 2 вариации

```
@dp.message(F.text.lower() == 'navigation calendar')
```

т.е. условно

```
@dp.message(F.text.lower() == 'navigation calendar for sales')
```

и

```
@dp.message(F.text.lower() == 'navigation calendar for orders')
```

... но по описанию следующий шаг

```
@dp.callback_query(SimpleCalendarCallback.filter())
```

срабатывает на выбор даты в календаре ... любом календаре ..
Не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы при выборе кнопки

```
@dp.message(F.text.lower() == 'navigation calendar for sales')
```

он перебрасывал на

```
@dp.callback_query(SimpleCalendarCallback.filter())
```

для 'navigation calendar for sales', а при выборе

```
@dp.message(F.text.lower() == 'navigation calendar for orders')
```

он бы перебрасывал на

```
@dp.callback_query(SimpleCalendarCallback.filter())
```

для 'navigation calendar for orders'
Надеюсь понятно объяснил.